# HTML within VBScript as a popup

Tags: html, vbscript

I've looked at [Use HTML tags in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24703598/use-html-tags-in-vbscript) and [How can I call a vbscript function from html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532120/how-can-i-call-a-vbscript-function-from-html), but I can't see what is wrong with my code. Can someone look it over and let me know why, when I click the OK button, the window doesn't close? I commented some lines out that I've tried and didn't work.

```
Dim objIE, objShell
Dim strDX

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strDX = "AT-0125B"

objIE.Navigate "about:blank"

objIE.Document.Title = "Covered Diagnosis"
objIE.ToolBar = False
objIE.Resizable = False
objIE.StatusBar = False
objIE.Width = 350
objIE.Height = 200
'objIE.Scrollbars="no"

' Center the Window on the screen
With objIE.Document.ParentWindow.Screen
    objIE.Left = (.AvailWidth - objIE.Width ) \ 2
    objIE.Top = (.Availheight - objIE.Height) \ 2
End With

objIE.document.body.innerHTML = "<b>" & strDX & " is a covered diagnosis code.</b><p>&nbsp;</p>" & _
"<center><input type='submit' value='OK' onclick='VBScript:ClickedOk()'></center>" & _
"<input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>"

objIE.Visible = True
'objShell.AppActivate "Covered Diagnosis"
'MsgBox objIE.Document.All.OK.Value
Function ClickedOk
'If objIE.Document.All.OK.Value = 1 Then
    'objIE.Document.All.OK.Value = 0
    'objShell.AppActivate "Covered Diagnosis"
    'objIE.Quit
    Window.Close()
'End If
End Function
```

Comment: your code sets the innerhtml, then executes all the code AFTER the innerhtml defition. at that point the button hasn't been clicked yet, so the `if` test fails, and window.close() never gets called.

Comment: Ok. I'm designing it after a working script, but there is a lot less code in mine that the original. I tested the OK.Value in the MsgBox and get 0. How would I do it so that it recognizes the button click?

Comment: your onclick would have to call a vb function that runs your `if` test, so it can test the "live" value as changed by the form, not the value that exists at the time you're defining the html.

Comment: Ok, see my updated code. I called a function, then had the function close the window. Now, the popup doesn't show at all. What am I missing?

Comment: you forgot `VBScript:`, so you're trying to call an undefined javascript function.

Comment: Still not showing. I do apologize. This is something kind of new to me. Should I be using a Sub instead of a Function?

Comment: no idea. never deal with VB before. but, as-modified, your onclick is going to execute javascript, not vbscript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClickedOk()` function is not part of the HTML source code of the new window. Your script starts a new Internet Explorer process, but HTML (or script) code in that process cannot use code from another process (in this case the script process):

```
yourscript.vbs --> ClickedOk()
     |                 ^
     |                 |
     |                 X
     v                 |
iexplore.exe   --> <input onclick='VBScript:ClickedOk()'>
```

You'd need [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) methods for communicating with other processes, but browsers usually restrict this kind of access due to security considerations.

So, when you click 'OK', it looks for a `ClickedOK` function and cannot find it. Thus it will not work.

To make it work, try something like this:

```
objIE.document.body.innerHTML = "<b>" & strDX & " is a covered diagnosis code.</b><p>&nbsp;</p>" & _
"<center><input type='submit' value='OK' onclick='self.close();'></center>" & _
"<input type='hidden' id='OK' name='OK' value='0'>"
```