# Create a vba message box that uses html

Tags: vba

How can I return a message box with functioning HTML tags using VBA?
example

```
    dim mtext as string
    mtext = "<em>hello</em> <br> world"
    msgbox mtext
```

Comment: short answer is you can't. long answer is...you really want to embed a really old insecure web browser control in a form to show some text? How about a rich text box control instead, where you can control the formatting and not have to depend on an HTML parser.

Comment: #FunFact: [only] in MS-Access there's still support for a [now deprecated] formattable MsgBox, if you know where to find it.

Comment: If you want to use HTML, perhaps something like this would work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27744288/4996248 but I really doubt that it would be worth it. Low-tech approach: just use things like "<<hello>> world" if you want to emphasize things. Maybe do a bit of ascii art.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. The `MsgBox` function is just a thin wrapper over a Win32 API function, and that function doesn't deal with HTML input. HTML is for web browsers, not desktop applications.

The closest thing you could get is a custom `UserForm` with a `RichTextBox` control, but that's OCX tech developped for Visual Basic 6.0 and probably won't work on x64 machines, not to mention that it will definitely break down if you need to distribute your macro to users that don't have the OCX on their machines.

---

A better alternative could be to make a COM-visible class library in your favorite .NET language (C#, VB.NET), and expose a custom `MessageBox` function that displays a WinForms dialog featuring a `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` control that can process and display RTF formatted text.

You then need to distribute and register your COM type library to your users.

In other words, it can be done - it only depends how badly you want it.

Comment: If I ever get around to building it, I will put it on github.

Answer (score 0):

I would custom design a form and then have the text set based on your needs specifically.  May I ask why you are wanting to use HTML codes?  Cause, it may be simple enough to create your own library/class to handle the processing, before pushing to a rich text box.  However, the Rich Text Box is only going to be in VB, like using VB Studio Express.  With VBA, you're sort of stuck...sorry.